# Tap-i18n is not enabled in the project level, check tap-i18n README

Tags: meteor, error-handling, internationalization, meteor-blaze

Trying to implement TAP-i18n in a Meteor-1.7 app. I have installed it, and have followed the setup as detailed on the page. The i18n JSON files are in startup/both/i18n/en and fr directory thus:

```
{
    "headers" : {
        "appheader"     : "OLTega",
        "home"          : "Home"
    }
}
```

Template implementation:

```
<template name="header">
  <a href="#intro">{{_ 'headers.home'}}</a>
</template>
```

I kept on getting this error:

```
Exception in defer callback: Error: No such function: _
    at blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:3214
    at Spacebars.call (spacebars.js?hash=547cf8e466d1d52603d19bd5f48fb5df184fd237:172)
    at Spacebars.mustacheImpl (spacebars.js?hash=547cf8e466d1d52603d19bd5f48fb5df184fd237:106)
    at Object.Spacebars.mustache (spacebars.js?hash=547cf8e466d1d52603d19bd5f48fb5df184fd237:110)
    at Blaze.View._render (app.js?hash=af2511f3e4a636f030d9ecbfdc553bf9ad12b1a6:400)
    at Blaze.View.doRender (blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:2086)
    at blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:1934
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:3744)
    at blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:1932
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:2271)
detectlang.js:16 tap-i18n is not enabled in the project level, check tap-i18n README
```

I have checked the README.md and donot understand this statement:

> tap-i18n can be used to internationalize projects and packages, but its behavior is determined by whether or not it's installed on the project level. We call these two work modes: enabled and disabled.

It is installed, and shows in the packages file. What am I to do to get it working?

Comment: you should give a try to `ostrio:i18n` which is actively maintained and keeps it simple

Comment: I don't seem to find any working example on this package. Could you kindly point me to any? I mean project implementation aside the repo doc. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? You can just create a new project and try it out, it takes 5-10 Minutes to set it up. The [wiki documentation](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/flow-router/wiki) is as with all their packages very detailed.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, religious and theistic invocations, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.